# How does pack work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am a tad confused about what I see here:

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
n = [ 65, 66, 67 ]
a.pack("A3A3A3")   #=> "a  b  c  "
a.pack("a3a3a3")   #=> "a\000\000b\000\000c\000\000"
n.pack("ccc")      #=> "ABC"
```

From the docs:

> Packs the contents of arr into a binary sequence according to the directives in aTemplateString (see the table below) Directives “A,'' “a,'' and “Z'' may be followed by a count, which gives the width of the resulting field.

Here are the directives:

[image]

So we're using the `A` directive 3 times it seems? What does it mean to pack the string `a` into an arbitrary binary string (space padded, count is width?) Can you help me understand the output? Why are there so many 0s?

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you're printing `"a"` but padding its length to 3 with spaces, hence the two spaces to get the total length to 3.

In the second case, you're doing the same but padding with null bytes instead (ASCII value 0). Null bytes in Ruby are printed (and can be read) using the escape syntax `\000` (this is *one* character), so `\000\000` is actually just two null bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `n` is irrelevant, so you can ignore it.

In the `pack` statements, the bytes `"a"`, `"b"` and `"c"` are concatenated ("packed") into a single string, with padding between them. The padding is such that the number of bytes (the width) taken up by the contents plus the padding equals the number provided.

So in the first `pack` statement, the `"a"` is padded with two spaces to make these three bytes: `"a.."` where I've put a `.` in place of the spaces to make it clear. That is concatenated with the `"b"` and the `"c"` similarly padded, to produce `"a..b..c.."`.

In the second `pack` statement, null characters (`'\000'`) are used instead of spaces. The `\xxx` notation (called an "escape sequence") means the byte with octal value `xxx`. It's used when there isn't a useful ASCII character (like 'a' or ' ') to show. A null character has no useful ASCII character, so the `\xxx` notation is used instead.