# What is this unpack doing? Can someone help me understand just a few letters?

Tags: ruby, unpack

I'm reading this code and I'm a tad confused as to what is going on. This code is using Ruby's `OpenSSL` library.

```
encrypted_message = cipher.update(address_string) + cipher.final
encrypted_message
=> "G\xCB\xE10prs\x1D\xA7\xD0\xB0\xCEmX\xDC@k\xDD\x8B\x8BB\xE1#!v\xF1\xDC\x19\xDD\xD0\xCA\xC9\x8B?B\xD4\xED\xA1\x83\x10\x1F\b\xF0A\xFEMBs'\xF3\xC7\xBC\x87\x9D_n\\z\xB7\xC1\xA5\xDA\xF4s \x99\\\xFD^\x85\x89s\e"
[3] pry(Encoder)> encrypted_message.unpack('H*')
=> ["47cbe1307072731da7d0b0ce6d58dc406bdd8b8b42e1232176f1dc19ddd0cac98b3f42d4eda183101f08f041fe4d427327f3c7bc879d5f6e5c7ab7c1a5daf47320995cfd5e8589731b"]
```

It seems that the `H` directive is this:

> hex string (high nibble first)

How are the escaped characters in the encrypted_message transformed into letters and numbers?

I think the heart of the issue is that I don't understand this. What is going on?

```
['A'].pack('H')
=> "\xA0"
```

Comment: It's just each byte of the string as two-digit hex string, no?

Comment: What is the ASCII code for `G`? Or `0`, `p`, `r`, or `s`?

Comment: You've posted [_"How does pack work in Ruby?"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482859/how-does-pack-work-in-ruby) yesterday and now you're asking how `['A'].pack('H')` works. I'm inclined to close this one as a duplicate ...

Comment: How did you even find that out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2011/07/20/ruby-pack-unpack.html) is a good explanation of Ruby's pack and unpack methods.

According to your question:

```
> ['A'].pack('H')
=> "\xA0"
```

A **byte** consists of 8 bits. A **nibble** consists of 4 bits. So a byte has two nibbles. The ascii value of ‘h’ is 104. Hex value of 104 is 68. This 68 is stored in two nibbles. First nibble, meaning 4 bits, contain the value 6 and the second nibble contains the value 8. In general we deal with high nibble first and going from left to right we pick the value 6 and then 8.

In the above case the input ‘A’ is not ASCII ‘A’ but the hex ‘A’. Why is it hex ‘A’. It is hex ‘A’ because the directive ‘H’ is telling pack to treat input value as hex value. Since ‘H’ is high nibble first and since the input has only one nibble then that means the second nibble is zero. So the input changes from ['A'] to ['A0'] .

Since hex value A0 does not translate into anything in the ASCII table the final output is left as it and hence the result is \xA0. The leading \x indicates that the value is hex value.