# Ruby pack and unpack. How is this hexadecimal conversion being done? Could use some assistance

Tags: ruby, encryption

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding some code:

Things I understand:
1. The use of the `Cipher` class and object and the encryption method.
2. The address_string and how it is using `|` as a delimiter.
3. The update.

My questions:
1. What is `cipher.final` doing?
2. What is the unpack doing?

```
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('AES-256-CFB').encrypt
  iv = cipher.random_iv
  cipher.key = Digest::SHA256.digest(KEY)
  address_string = addresses.map{ |addr| addr.strip }.push(identifier).join('|')
  encrypted_message = cipher.update(address_string) + cipher.final
  binding.pry
  encrypted_message.unpack('H*')[0]
```

I see this in my terminal:

```
 encrypted_message
=> ".YI\xCA\xAC\x17\xF2\xBF\x1C^b\x8C[|\xB8YU\x1F\xCBn/\xE5\xA0\x15\x8Aa\ef\xAF>\x7F\x8A"
[2] pry(Mixer)> encrypted_message.unpack('H*')
=> ["2e5949caac17f2bf1c5e628c5b7cb859551fcb6e2fe5a0158a611b66af3e7f8a"]
```

I understand the basics of binary and hexadecimal... but I'm still having trouble understanding what I see.

1. What is the encrypted message format? What are the slashes and the `\x`s. Is it hexadecimal? How do you know? What is the `.YI` leading part?
2. How are they converting this to hexa? Can you show an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48492676/1672429

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`encrypted_message` is a string starting with the characters `.YI`. Let's convert those characters to Hex and then binary using the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set) table:

```
ASCII  .        |Y        |I
Hex    2    e   |5    9   |4    9
Binary 0010 1110|0101 1001|0100 1001
```

Notice that the hex is what you see at the beginning of the `unpack(H*)` result. If you were to call `encrypted_message.unpack("B*")` (bit string), you would similarly see it start with

```
001011100101100101001001
```

The point is

1. There is *no* "encrypted message format". `encrypted_message` is meaningless, structureless binary data.
2. When you call `unpack`, you're saying "Take this meaningless binary data, and show it to me with a different representation." In this case, hexadecimal digits. You can similarly see it as binary, like I did above. Or you can look at it as ASCII characters (the default), with `\x` indicating a byte that doesn't have an ASCII representation. It's all the same binary data just being presented in different human-readable ways.

Comment: This is very clear, but what do you mean by structureless books data? The first character is a period and then a Y... Which are not binary right?

Comment: So the original message is already encoded in ASCII format? But it really is just structureless binary data?

Comment: @Jwan622 Ruby only escapes non-printable characters when printing binary strings, so printable characters within the ASCII range are not distinguishable from ordinary text.

Comment: @Stefan and I guess a correlary to what you're saying is that Ruby auto converts binary to ascii characters?

Comment: @Jwan622 for displaying purposes, yes. Although `"\x68\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F"` might be more consistent, it's much harder to read than `"hello"` ;-)